# Заменить в строке необходимые символы java

Tags: java

```
    String[] u_s = {":","*","?","<",">"};
    String file_name = "Name :d*?f<> file";
    String newfilename = null;

    for (String u_s_one : u_s) {

        if(file_name.contains(u_s_one)) {
            newfilename = file_name.replace(u_s_one,"-");
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(new filename);
```

В идеале цикл должен определять есть ли в строке значения из массива и если есть заменять их на "-", не могу описать такую логику. Конечно можно это сделать не элегантно, много `replace`'ов, но хочется сделать правильно.

Пытаюсь получить вывод типа: `Name -d--f-- file`

ИТОГ:

```
String[] u_s = {":","*","?","<",">"};
String us2 = "[:*?<>]";
String file_name = "Name :d*?f<> file";
String newfilename = null;

for (String u_s_one : u_s) {

    if (file_name.contains(u_s_one)) {
        newfilename = file_name.replaceAll(us2, "-");
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(newfilename);
```

Comment: Зачем вам там цикл?

Comment: @КириллМалышев оба цикла для проверки исходной строки на наличие заменяемых символов

Comment: У вас там один цикл. И зачем проверять? Если символов таких нет, они и так заменяться не будут. А в вашем коде несколько раз одно и то же будет происходить.

Comment: @КириллМалышев да вы правы, трех колесный велосипед получился)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String file_name = "Name :d*?f<> file";
String newfilename = file_name.replaceAll("[:*?<>]", "-");
System.out.println(newfilename);
```

Comment: сработало) отлично

Comment: Примите, пожалуйста, ответ, если он вам помог.

Comment: осталось научится находить такие строки

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Может, вам стоит задать новый вопрос?

Comment: перебирать все варианты из нужных символов что бы найти строку подходящую под условие опять же много if, может есть подобное элегантное решение?

Comment: Лучше задайте полноценный вопрос с описанием задачи и примером.